# Get number of rows when a value for a whole database

Tags: sql-server

I have a hypothetical database with 1000 tables. Some tables have a field called `person_id`. I want to find out how many of rows in the **entire** database that has a value of `10` for every table that has the field `person_id` without writing a query for every table. Is this possible to do in a single SQL statement?

Comment: Only if you consider creating and executing a dynamic sql statement to be a "single SQL statement".

Comment: so i would have to do a TSQL script...

Comment: “Is this possible?” [is a bad question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/). Show us what you have. Show us what you tried. Tell us what happened when you tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working dynamic SQL solution. I guess it's technically a few statements, though... I'd love to see if someone could come up with a way to just execute the query in a single statement without a variable, like EXEC( CAST('... etc, but I'm not sure you can do that.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) 

SELECT @sql = CAST('SELECT SUM(c) as ttl FROM (' + 
(SELECT STUFF((SELECT ' union all select count(*) c from ' + TABLE_NAME 
    + ' where person_id = 10'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'person_id'
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 10, '')) + ')sq' AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```